# User Login Page using Spring MVC + Hibernate + PostGreSQL connection

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, postgresql-9.2

I was trying to setup a signin page using spring mvc + hibernate + postgresql connection.
After several hits and runs, the below code worked well. I faced several issues while setting this up. Comments from @M. Deinum helped me in getting this done. Also some useful materials which he posted in reply to my earlier queries helped me in understanding spring mvc + hibernate concepts. So people who have issues can refer the below code. Just sharing it for reference.

My dispatcher servlet file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->
    <annotation-driven/>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>


     <beans:bean id="userValidator" class="com.springapp.mvc.validator.UserValidator"/>

        <!--Data source has the database information -->
     <beans:bean id="dataSource"
                class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
         <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
         <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
         <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
          <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- SessonFactory for Hibernate -->
        <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.springapp.mvc.domain"/>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


 <!-- Transaction Manager -->
 <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
             class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
 </beans:bean>

 <context:property-placeholder location="/jdbc.properties"/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

 <!-- bind your messages.properties -->
 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
             id="messageSource">
     <beans:property name="basename" value="locale\messages"/>

     <!-- <beans:property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />  -->
 </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

My LoginDao class file is

```
    package com.springapp.mvc.dao;

import com.springapp.mvc.domain.Users;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Transactional
@Repository("LoginDao")
public class LoginDao {


    public SessionFactory getMy_sessionfactory() {
        return my_sessionfactory;
    }

    @Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
    public void setMy_sessionfactory(SessionFactory my_sessionfactory) {
        this.my_sessionfactory = my_sessionfactory;
    }

    private SessionFactory my_sessionfactory;

    public Long findByUname(Users loginForm) {
        System.out.println("Hi Dao" + loginForm.getUname());
        Session session = my_sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
        String hql = "select count(u.uname) from Users u where u.uname = ? and u.pass = ?";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql).setString(0, loginForm.getUname()).setString(1, loginForm.getPass());
        System.out.println("query" + query);
        System.out.println("query ur" + query.uniqueResult());

        Long count = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
        return count;
    }


}
```

My Domain class file is

```
    package com.springapp.mvc.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")

public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "uname")
    private String uname;

    @Column(name = "pass")
    private String pass;


    private Long user_count;

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }


    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public Long getUser_count() {
        return user_count;
    }

    public void setUser_count(Long user_count) {
        this.user_count = user_count;
    }

}
```

My Controller class file is

```
    package com.springapp.mvc.controller;

import com.springapp.mvc.domain.Users;
import com.springapp.mvc.service.LoginService;
import com.springapp.mvc.validator.UserValidator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SigninController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService lsp;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "appstore";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(ModelMap model) {
        Users loginForm = new Users();
        model.addAttribute("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "signin";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginsuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginSuccess(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") Users loginObj, ModelMap model, BindingResult result) {
        Long count = this.lsp.validateLogin(loginObj);
        loginObj.setUser_count(count);
        UserValidator userValidator = new UserValidator();
        userValidator.validate(loginObj, result);


        model.addAttribute("message1", loginObj.getUname());
        System.out.println("result error" + result.getAllErrors());
        System.out.println("result error count" + result.getErrorCount());
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "signin";
        } else {
            return "loginsuccess";
        }
    }
```

My POM.xml file is as follows.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>D2DCOMM</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>D2DCOMM</name>


    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-r699049</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Validator class

```
    package com.springapp.mvc.validator;

import com.springapp.mvc.domain.Users;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public class UserValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return Users.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);

    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "uname", "Empty.UsersName");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "pass", "Empty.UsersPass");
        Users user = (Users) obj;
        System.out.println("count from validator!!!!!" + user.getUser_count());
        if (user.getUser_count() > 0) {

        } else {
            errors.reject("User.Details.Mismatch");
        }
    }

}
```

My messages_en_US_properties file located at (src/main/resources/locale/messages_en_US_properties) file is as follows

```
Empty.UsersName = User Name is required!
Empty.UsersPass = Password is required!
User.Details.Mismatch  = No user details found.Please sign up.
```

My jdbc_properties file

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
jdbc.username=postgr
jdbc.password=postgr
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several things.

```
@Transactional
@Repository("LoginDao")
public class LoginDao {
public void findByUname(Users loginForm) {
    System.out.println("Hi Dao" + loginForm.getUname());
    Session session = my_sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query =  session.getNamedQuery("loginUser.findByUname").setString("userid", loginForm.getUname());
   Users loginObj = (Users)session.getNamedQuery("Users.findByUname").setParameter("id", loginForm.getUname());
           // getNamedQuery("loginUser.findByUname").setParameter("id", loginForm.getUname()).uniqueResult();

}
```

First your `LoginDao` has no field named `my_sessionfactory` at least not in the code you show. Next there is no named query with the name **loginUser.findByUname**, there is a **Users.findByUname** query. Finally you are trying to cast the `Query` to a `Users` object, that is never going to work

Change the dao as follows (I also assumed you wanted to return the result).

```
@Transactional
@Repository("LoginDao")
public class LoginDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Users findByUname(Users loginForm) {
        System.out.println("Hi Dao" + loginForm.getUname());
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query =  session.getNamedQuery("Users.findByUname");
        query.setString("userid", loginForm.getUname());
        query.setString("password", loginForm.getPassword());
        Users loginObj = (Users) query.uniqueResult();
        return loginObj;
    }   
}
```

The named queries you use have to be HQL queries not SQL queries so you need to rewrite your queries to include the property names NOT column names.

The validation is done wrong simply include a `BindingResult` in your method signature and pass that into the validator. Also don't add the user object to the model, it is already present.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SigninController {

@Autowired
private LoginService lsp;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/loginsuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String loginSuccess(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") Users loginObj, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
      UserValidator userValidator = new UserValidator();
  userVaidator.validate(result, loginObj);          

      Long count = this.lsp.validateLogin(loginObj);
      model.addAttribute("message1", loginObj.getUname());
      System.out.println("result error"+result.getAllErrors());
      System.out.println("result error count"+result.getErrorCount());
      if (result.hasErrors()) {
          return "signin";
      } else {
          return "loginsuccess";
      }
  }
```

Another solution would be to add the validator to the binder (this allows you to simply add the @Valid annotation and spring will do the validation for you). For this add a method annotated with @InitBinder and add the validator.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SigninController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService lsp;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginsuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginSuccess(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") @Valid Users loginObj, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        Long count = this.lsp.validateLogin(loginObj);
        model.addAttribute("message1", loginObj.getUname());
        System.out.println("result error"+result.getAllErrors());
        System.out.println("result error count"+result.getErrorCount());
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "signin";
        } else {
            return "loginsuccess";
        }
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new UserValidator());
    }
}
```

Regarding the validation of wrong passwords you should put the password in your query and retrieve the object with both username/password as part of the query.

Comment: Thanks it worked.But one more issue with below code.              

public Long findByUname(Users loginForm) {
       Session session = my_sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query =  session.getNamedQuery("Users.findByUname");
        query.setString("userid", loginForm.getUname());
        query.setString("passid", loginForm.getPassword());
        Long count = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
        return count; 

        @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUname", query = "select count(u.uname) from Users u " +
                "where u.uname = :userid and u.pass = :passid")

Comment: In the above comment, I have sent u the changes which i made in LoginDao method where i compare the input username and password with the database. Also have given the modified named query. But it doesn't works. Not sure how to pass two parameters such as Username and Password to the Query.

Comment: Simply add a second `setString()` method, those can be chained or called seperatly.Can you update your initial post with your new LoginDao code? That makes it a lot easier to read. Also it would be nice to specify what doesn't work? Do you get an error or no result?

Comment: Just noticed your error. THe query you write isn't a SQL query but a HQL. This means you need to reference object attributes and not the name of the column. Your query references the **pass** column whereas it should reference the **password** attribute of the object. Hibernate will translate that object query into a SQL query.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated Login Dao & Controller class file in my original post and added the Validator class to perform validation. As you said I tried two set string for Uname and Pass. Issue 1- Mine is a simple SQL query and not a HQL query. Issue 2- Aside its logging in even when trying logging in with incorrect username and password. Issue 3 - Also i have set validation for blank username . But it doesn't works. It even accepts blank username. these are the three issues which i face now. how to validate username / password wrt to DB.

Comment: I strsongly suggest you readup on JPA/Hibernate, the query must be a HQL and not a SQL query! You also seem to lack a basic understanding how Spring MVC and Validation work, I suggest a read of the [reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html). I updated the answer to include the modified controller.

Comment: Hi,I forgot to update my comment about the HQL/SQL confusion. Anyways thanks for your comment and updated code in controller. Could you pls suggest the best way to execute SQL Query (select,insert,update,delete) using Hibernate & Spring MVC rather using NamedQueries approach. Have read other blogs where i couldn't find a detailed document about this. Can u pls share links if you have this sort of examples. @M. Deinum.

Comment: You don't want to execute SQL queries... If you want SQL then why use Hibernate at all?! When you start executing SQL queries with Hibernate you are, IMHO that is, reaching a slippery slope...

Comment: Let me put my question simple & sweet. Actually I am creating a signup page wherein the user feeds in the uname,fname,lname,pass etc such that these details gets inserted into the DB as a new row. How to proceed with it. Pls fwd any examples that would help to do insert function as mentioned above.

Comment: As mentioned earlier I suggest you readup on Hibernate and how to use that (I recommend the book [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer3/) as a read but at least read the Hibernate documentation. After validation, simply let hibernate store the object (if validation succeeds). The whole purpose of using an ORM mapper is that the heavy lifting, regarding SQL, is done for you by that ORM mapper. You simply do something like `getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(user);` that is all.